# Trying to write a pure virtual method but I apparently have the syntax wrong?

Tags: c++, complex-numbers, pure-virtual

Here's my code:

```
#include <string>
#include <complex>

class a{
protected:
    std::string name;

public:
    a(std::string _name): name(_name) {};

    virtual void inside(const complex<double> &b, const complex<double> &t) const = 0;
};
```

But visual studio is giving me these errors for the line where I have declared the virtual method:

```
Error   1   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Error   2   error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '<'
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Chris – you've got a couple of correct answers here. It'd be good to accept one as correct. You could do the same for your other questions: for 30 of your 37 you haven't accepted an answer. You can get 60 reputation for that lot (nearly doubling your current total), and it will improve your chance of getting answers in future. – just a thought.

Comment: @Benjohn Thank you! I'll do this, sorry I'm not very used to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to `std::string name;`  that you have earlier, the template `complex` is properly called `std::complex`

Answer (score 2):

While it doesn't look like it from the errors, what's wrong here is that you've missed out the namespace specification on the type `complex<double>`. It's also in the `std` namespace, so you need to tell the compiler this. Try:

```
virtual void inside(const std::complex<double> &b, const std::complex<double> &t) const = 0;
```